# How do I do math using quarter-end dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following table. Each value in the "quarter" column is a calendar quarter-end (e.g. 3/31, 6/30, 9/30, 12/31) with data going back to the 1970s:

```
name   | value | quarter
-------|-------|----------
bob    | 12    | 2014-3-31
jane   | 9     | 2014-6-30
bob    | 12    | 2014-9-30
dave   | 12    | 2014-12-31
bob    | 7     | 2015-3-31
mary   | 17    | 2015-6-30
mary   | 12    | 2015-9-30
```

I am selecting some records based on if they are older than a specified quarter-end date: e.g. "SELECT rows that are >= to 2 quarters ago" or ">= 15 quarters ago", etc.

Finding records from 1 year ago from the most recent quarter is easy:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE quarter >= (SELECT max(quarter) - interval '12 month' FROM mytable)

name   | value | quarter
-------|-------|----------
bob    | 12    | 2014-9-30
dave   | 12    | 2014-12-31
bob    | 7     | 2015-3-31
mary   | 17    | 2015-6-30
mary   | 12    | 2015-9-30
```

However, I can't figure out how to select records that are based on quarters, say 2 quarters away (keep in mind that while the data goes back to the 1970s I don't have every quarter in there so I am missing some quarters like 12/31/1987, 9/30/2011, etc):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE quarter >= (SELECT max(quarter) - interval '2 quarter' FROM mytable)

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "2 quarter"
```

EDIT:
The ending point will always be relative to the max(quarter) in the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function to convert dates to "quarters" (i. e. sequential integers), like this:

```
create function quarternum(d date) returns integer as $$
  select extract(year from d)::integer*4 +
         extract(quarter from d)::integer;
$$ language sql;
```

For example:

```
postgres=# select quarternum('2014-3-31');
 quarternum 
------------
       8057
(1 row)

postgres=# select quarternum('2014-6-30'); -- next quarter gets +1 to its number
 quarternum 
------------
       8058
(1 row)
```

With such function you can use simple integer math, e. g.

```
-- 2 quarters away
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE quarternum(quarter) >=
      (SELECT quarternum(max(quarter)) - 2 FROM mytable)
```

Moreover, you can probably use `quarternum(current_date)` instead of calculating `max` over the table.

Comment: That's nice! Why multiply the year by 4?

Comment: In order to get unique and continuous quarter numbers. Four quarters per year, hence multiplication by 4.